# Code signing entitlement for inter-app-audio

Tags: xcode, api, code-signing

I am not sure why is Apple rejecting my build for this reason:

> **Invalid Code Signing Entitlements** - Your application bundle's
>   signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported.
>   Please check your Xcode project's code signing entitlements
>   configuration, and remove any unneeded entitlements.
>
> Specifically, key "inter-app-audio" is not supported.

My app is not even using that API. Our app basically uses AFNetworking and SVGHud libraries and it captures video / photo and uploads it to the web server.

Any reason why Apple is rejecting the build? And how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We were getting same error... this is because the key "inter-app-audio" was enabled in our application ID.

We disabled this feature and re-created the App Id and re-generated the binary with updated provisioning profile and uploaded.
Now it’s working fine and the status is set to "Waiting For Review"

Comment: Thanks.. this was making us go crazy :)